# SSAS 2012 TABULAR : Data load testing using MDX

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx, ssas-tabular

I have a model developed in Tabular 2012. When I connect to the cube, I see FACT and DIMENSION tables listed.
I am not a developer - I am just asked to test the data load.

I just need to locate an example record from my source DB in FACT( Or Dimension ) table in the cube.  I goggled it well, but could not find anything relevant as the the MDX queries I explored were always using some [Measure].blah blah to retrieve the data. Developer has defined just 1 measure in the DB. Is it possible to retrieve 1 row using MDX just like select 8 from table in SQL?

My problem is that even if I put one fact column on the columns axis and dimension key on row- axis, it just retrieves value 1.

Answer (score 1):

I was under the impression that tabular did not have multi-demnsional cubes but has a "tabular model" as the underlying structure.

If you are using `mdx` and want several columns of data with just one measure then use `CROSSJOIN`:

```
SELECT  
  [Measures].[X] ON COLUMNS,  
{CROSSJOIN (
   [Dimension1].[someLevel].members
  ,[Dimension1].[someLevel].members
  ,[Dimension1].[someLevel].members
  ,[Dimension1].[someLevel].members) }
ON ROWS  
FROM [cubeName]
```

Alternative syntax is:

```
SELECT  
  [Measures].[X] ON COLUMNS,  
  [Dimension1].[someLevel].members
  *[Dimension2].[someLevel].members
  *[Dimension3].[someLevel].members
  *[Dimension4].[someLevel].members
ON ROWS  
FROM [cubeName]
```